# Where to place a (class) dependency in another javascript class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, constructor

I have a class called `Tour` that has a method with a dependency on another class called `City`

I can put the dependency at the top of the file, as in

```
const City = require './City'
class Tour {
...
```

but it seems a bit odd to have the dependency listed before the class like that.
I can move it to the method where I use it, as in:

```
insertAfter(afterCityName, newCityName, appendAtEnd=true) {
  const City = require('./City');
  const cities = this.cities;
  ...
```

but having it within a method also seems not ideal.

Ideally I would think the constructor but every attempt I've made has been the wrong syntax, for examples:

```
constructor(cities=[]) {
  this.cities = cities;
  ...
  const City = require('./City');  // No, assigned but never used
  City = require('./City');  // No, City is not defined
  this.City = require('./City'); // No, City is not defined
}
```

How to place it in the constructor (and still Capitalize The Class) ?

Comment: Why does it seem odd to have a dependency listed before the class? Seems pretty standard to me.

Comment: In Node we put every import/require at the top of the file. So 1st idea is best here.

Comment: `require()` is blocking and synchronous.  You want to get all the `require()` statements done at module load time (when blocking, synchronous I/O is fine) and don't want to be doing any of them later once your server is up and running and processing requests.  In addition, it's much more declarative for a module to specify what it depends upon at the start of the file.  It's somewhat analogous to the C/C++ convention of specifying the headers you need to include at the start of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The convention I've seen and prefer is at the very top of the file. This makes it abundantly clear what your imports are. "Sneaky imports" in the middle of the file can lead to surprises.

When you're refactoring things and need to move files around it's easy to click through one file to the next quickly inspecting the top to check that the import paths are set correctly. This is not the case with inline imports.

Keep in mind `require()` is being retired, it's `import` from here on out, where `import` works best at the top of the file, as in:

```
import City from './City';
```

This style fits in well with other conventions like Python, Ruby, or C and C++ which use conventions like `#include <city.h>`.